# How do I import an entire column from an Excel Sheet

Tags: import, data, excel

The Wolfram Documentation gives information on how to import an entire sheet, and an entire row, but not an entire column.

Currently, the code I have been trying to contort into a working form is:

```
voltage =  Import["July 6th 2016.xlsx", "Data", 2, 3}]
```

This will import the 3rd row of the 2nd sheet.  I cannot seem to figure out how to import a column instead though.

Comment: Try something like: `Import[yourExcelfile][[sheetNumber, All, columnNumber]]`.

Comment: Is All a general command that I can commonly use outside of this function?  It seems mighty useful.

Comment: AFAIK All is a commonly used symbol for that purpose but doesn't implement any functionality itself. The function for which it is used must handle it correctly, which many of the builtins do, Part and Take are prominent examples, Import is another (depends on the format). You have to check the documentation for the function (or format) in question to find out if and how All is supported...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!